# Modified data is not saving to database in entity framework database first

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

I was writing code for changing the passwords but I don't know the reason why the data is not updated to the database. I have built custom membership table and membership Provider class. Here enitiy named IVRControlPanelEntities is generated from entity framework. I have following function to change password.

```
 public bool ChangePassword(string username, string oldPassword, string newPassword)
        {
            IVRControlPanelMembershipProvider memberservice = new IVRControlPanelMembershipProvider();
            if (!memberservice.ValidateUser(username, oldPassword) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(newPassword.Trim()))
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                using (IVRControlPanelEntities db = new IVRControlPanelEntities())
                {
                    User user = GetUser(username);
                   // string hash = FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(newPassword.Trim(), "md5");
                    string PasswordSalt = CreateSalt();
                    user.PasswordSalt = PasswordSalt;
                    user.Password = CreatePasswordHash(newPassword, PasswordSalt);
                    db.SaveChanges();


                }
               return true;
            }

        }
```

**Problems:**
I try changing the password, all is working fine but data for new password is not updated to the table. I have also searched for reason and use following code:
1.

```
db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

2.

```
db.Users.Attach(user);
                 db.ApplyCurrentValues("Users", user);
```

None of above is working and also use **TryUpdateModel()** function but it's not detecting .

It may be due to state of object is not defined, how can I solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If method GetUser uses different context, then data will not be updated.

Try this:

```
User user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.UserName == username);
               // string hash = FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(newPassword.Trim(), "md5");
                string PasswordSalt = CreateSalt();
                user.PasswordSalt = PasswordSalt;
                user.Password = CreatePasswordHash(newPassword, PasswordSalt);
                db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Thanks karaxuna now it shows effect in the database thanks a lot